# Add anchors to enable direct linking to detailed reason on "What topics can I ask about here?" page and others

Tags: feature-request, comments, help-center

When reviewing and helping new users to ask better questions reviewers refer to "how to" pages

- [How do I ask a good
  question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [What topics
  can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

in comments to asker.

To provide better feedback reviewer should also give a bit more detailed reason what should be fixed in question if possible.

Currently it is possible by copying text from page like

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work
>   you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
>   difficulty you are having solving it.

or writing something like *see especially chapter 3*.

This would be easier if there was something similar to a feature as the sharing answer is. Something like a direct link / anchor to a position on the page where the detailed message is.

Comment: I've wanted these for a long time. It'd be nice if such anchors existed on all pages in the help center, at least for `<hX>` elements and lists.

Comment: Or maybe we could add something like 'default comments' for users with a minimum reputation: eg. "Please add an MCVE (help link)", ...

Comment: @MEE That would be great. It could be something like flagging is now: open some dialog having "standard" stuff to choose. It would then create a comment with shorter text and a link to a more detailed anchored explanation in a help center page. I have such a list currently in a text file from which i copy paste comments.

Comment: @MEE and pirho There is the [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](//stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) userscript/extension which allows pre-created auto-comments to be used on questions, answers, etc. It contains some default comments, but there are a variety of pre-made lists floating around (e.g. [SOCVR's](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments). You can, of course, create your own comments. It doesn't solve what's asked in this question, but it is significantly more convenient than copy-&-pasting from a text file.

Comment: It would also be nice to have anchors when referencing certain canonical posts on the main Q&A site.

Comment: Related MSE post: [Can we have anchors for the bullets in the \[help/on-topic\] list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300028/335251) – That one was [status-declined] [back in February 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361176/335251) as something that wouldn't be prioritized/taken on at the time... I don't think that precludes it from ever being implemented, though.

Comment: Other relevant MSE posts: [Linking to subheaders of a help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322237/335251) (of which [Add anchors to the how-to-ask and how-to-answer pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89440/335251) is basically a subset), [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894/335251) (tangentially related, at least)

Comment: And a related newer MSO post from 2020: [Can we have some anchor for the lifelines we are throwing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399426/1478931) – It might make sense to close this as a duplicate of that request, since that one's a broader request about adding anchors on Help Center pages in general (which isn't currently possible).