# Please add anchors to (at least) "What are Tags" help page

Tags: feature-request, tags, help-center

https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Similar to [Add anchors to enable direct linking to detailed reason on "What topics can I ask about here?" page and others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360239/add-anchors-to-enable-direct-linking-to-detailed-reason-on-what-topics-can-i-as) request.

This is actually important as a means to inform users why, for example, a title was edited to remove an intra-title tag.  There shouldn't be any help pages without anchors to main sections.

Comment: Old dupe with no answer: [Add anchors to enable direct linking to detailed reason on “What topics can I ask about here?” page and others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360239/215552). Looks like it works within the Markdown help page? [Linking to sub-anchors in the “Markdown help” page not working as well as they could](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102809/linking-to-sub-anchors-in-the-markdown-help-page-not-working-as-well-as-they-c)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yep, the first one I linked to, I missed the second one though. From 2011 :/ This seems like an obvious one to me, and it'd be nice to be able to link to this stuff.

Comment: How did I miss that? Need more coffee, obvs. You got my vote.

Comment: Closely related if not duplicate (MSE): [Make magic links to help sections consistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314848/make-magic-links-to-help-sections-consistent)

Comment: Unfortunately, the help center doesn't support anchor links at all; the only way to get direct links is to break a page up into multiple pages. Yes, this is often frustrating.

Comment: @Shog9 What does it mean "does not support"? Anchors are pretty basic HTML; what's the issue that prevents their use?

Comment: You guys aren't using some crappy off-the-shelf CMS, are you @Shog9? :)

Comment: Hell no, @heretic - only crappy bespoke in-house CMSs here!

Comment: Related requests on MSE: [Linking to subheaders of a help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322237/335251), and [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894/335251) (tangentially related, at least)

Comment: And a related newer MSO post from 2020: [Can we have some anchor for the lifelines we are throwing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399426/1478931) – It might make sense to close this as a duplicate of that request, since that one's a broader request about adding anchors on Help Center pages in general (which isn't currently possible).