# Can we have some anchor for the lifelines we are throwing?

Tags: support, feature-request, help-center

Although most of the help center pages are concise enough to be self sufficient, some other do contain a lot of information, and those are also the one we probably use the most, for example the magic ones, [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Just now, I also encountered the lack of anchors on the page explaining what is [meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), because I just wanted to point at the difference of meaning of the voting in here compared to other Q&A.

So the question is: would it be possible to have an anchoring system on the sub-titles of the help center pages?

I am thinking of something visual like they do, e.g. on docker.com, where you have a link icon appearing when you hover over a title:

> [image: Anchor link appaering on hover]

<sup>*For ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground*</sup>

Comment: For the record, on Chrome these days you can [link to a text fragment](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/06/google-pushes-text-fragment-links-with-new-chrome-extension/). For example, here is a link to the voting heading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta#:~:text=Voting%20is%20different%20on%20meta. But I agree, permalink buttons would be more useful.

Comment: There was an old, kind of similar request before for the `[ask]` and `[help/on-topic]` pages: [Add anchors to enable direct linking to detailed reason on “What topics can I ask about here?” page and others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360239/2745495). It's been ~3 years, still no answer.

Comment: The Post is not very clear, with many Grammar Mistakes (between Singular/Plural), both in Title + Body... // "Lifeline(s)" = "Life Buoys" in some "pictured way"...? (Seems to be the name of some Anti-Suicide Prevention Organisation + Genealogy Software...) "Anchor(s)" = "Magic Link(s)"...? // The last Line of the Screenshot is half cut vertically...

Comment: @chivracq you can suggest an [edit] to help to clarify the question.

Comment: @snakecharmerb (funny Name btw), nope I can't, this is 'Meta' and I have <2k-Rep... ("Suggested Edits" are not allowed on 'Meta'...)

Comment: @chivracq They aren't? Well TIL.  In any case, I think the OP is [punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun), as "anchor" can refer to both a weight attached to a ship to maintain position or a linkable location within an HTML page. The image truncation doesn't really matter as the important part is the symbol after "Foreground".

Comment: *Only* related to the title: [Lifeboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/68258#68258) and [Lifejacket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/68258#68258)

Comment: Related request on MSE: [Linking to subheaders of a help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322237/335251)